# How do I roll a dice and store the total number using Python3.4

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter
import random

def rollDice():
   x=random.randint(1,6)
   total=0
   if x == 1:
   total+=1
   ....
print(total)
```

I would like to add each number I roll in `.rollDice` and store into `total` , and maximum is 50. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean _maximum is 50_? Until `total` becomes 50 or more or roll the dice 50 times? Also you don't have to check the value of `x`. Just add it to the total like so: `total += x`

Comment: It sounds like you are asking us to do your homework.

Comment: Not sure what this has got to do with tkinter. You already got the `+=` operator, so go into a while loop (while total is less than or equal to 50 I.e`<=`) and each time add whatever the result of the dice roll was.

Comment: @BryanOakley actually this is an extra task for me , i am currently on my first semester,*intro to programming*  .but yea ,Im asking u for my homework` enhancement. :D

Comment: @PaulRooney Thanks For the help ,and now im trying to do in tkinter
adding label and button , once you press the button , it will roll a number one time.
This is my simple work
and sorry for the grammar ,my English not so good.
`w = Button(root,text="Roll A Dice",command=rollDice,wraplengt=30,bg="pink").grid(row=6, column=1)
root.mainloop()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PaulRooney says, i am not sure what `tkinter` has to do with this. From what i understand, you want to roll a dice until your `total` reaches or exceeds 50.. So here is my take on this:

```
from random import randint

def rollDice():
    return randint(1,6)

total = 0
while total < 50:
    new_roll = rollDice()
    total += new_roll
    print('You rolled a {}. The new total is {}'.format(new_roll, total))
# You rolled a 3. The new total is 3
# You rolled a 3. The new total is 6
# You rolled a 4. The new total is 10
# You rolled a 6. The new total is 16
# You rolled a 2. The new total is 18
# You rolled a 1. The new total is 19
# You rolled a 5. The new total is 24
# You rolled a 5. The new total is 29
# You rolled a 4. The new total is 33
# You rolled a 5. The new total is 38
# You rolled a 2. The new total is 40
# You rolled a 3. The new total is 43
# You rolled a 4. The new total is 47
# You rolled a 6. The new total is 53
```

Comment: Thanks ya :D
If possible to add a button to "Roll A Dice" ?

Comment: It's possible, but that would better be asked as a separate question since it's essentially unrelated to this one.